# the type travellingsalesman.city already contains a definition for longitude, what can i do?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

The type travellingsalesman.city already contains a definition for longitude, what can i do? I have no idea why this error is showing.
        public class City
        {
            int longitude;
            int latitude;
            int DegreesToRadians;

```
        public City(string name, double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            Name = name;
            latitude = latitude;
            longitude = longitude;

        }

        public string Name { set; get; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }

        public double GetDistanceFromPosition(double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            var R = 6371; //raduis of the earth in km
            var dLat = DegreesToRadians(latitude - Latitude);
            var dlon = DegreesToRadians(longitude - Longitude);
            var a =
                Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2) +
                Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(Latitude)) *
                Math.Cos(DegreesToRadinas(Latitude)) *
                Math.Sin(dlon / 2) * Math.Sin(dlon / 2)
                ;
            var c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));
            var d = R * c; // distance in km
            return d;

        }

        private static double DegreesToRaduis(double deg)
        {
            return deg * System.Math.PI / 180;
        }

        public byte[] ToBinaryString()
        {
            var result = new byte[6];
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your public property is lowercase "l" longitude, the param passed into your constructor has the same name. Change your property to be Longitude

Comment: I've just tried that, it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
    public City(string name, double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        Name = name;
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;

    }

    public string Name { set; get; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
```

**EDIT**

Full source code for a console app, no errors (DegreesToRadians was misspelled a few times in your example too).

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TravelingSalesman ts = new TravelingSalesman();
        ts.City("Greenwich", 0.0, 0.0);
    }
}

public class TravelingSalesman
{
    public void City(string name, double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        Name = name;
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
    }

    public string Name { set; get; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public double GetDistanceFromPosition(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        var R = 6371; //raduis of the earth in km
        var dLat = DegreesToRadians(latitude - Latitude);
        var dlon = DegreesToRadians(longitude - Longitude);
        var a =
            Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2) +
            Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(Latitude)) *
            Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(Latitude)) *
            Math.Sin(dlon / 2) * Math.Sin(dlon / 2)
            ;
        var c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));
        var d = R * c; // distance in km
        return d;

    }

    private static double DegreesToRadians(double deg)
    {
        return deg * System.Math.PI / 180;
    }

    public byte[] ToBinaryString()
    {
        var result = new byte[6];
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work mate. Thanks for giving it a go :)